# sherlock action item style for button in custom action bar layout

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

is there a way to apply sherlock action item style (which is default touch feedback and long click feedback and click area - width/height) to button in customized action bar layout ?

src/MainActivity.java

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_main);
```

res/layout/actionbar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- Home button -->
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic_home"
        android:onClick="clickButtonHome" />

    <!-- Centered text -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_actionbar_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <!-- Cancel button -->
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ic_cancel"
        android:onClick="clickButtonHome" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton` for the `ImageButton`'s style. To achieve the long-click toast effect you'll need to use Roman Nurik's [CheetSheet](https://gist.github.com/3982005) class.

For future reference, all of the ActionBarSherlock styles and themes have the same naming convention as the native styles and themes but with 'Sherlock' instead of 'Holo'. For example,

- `Widget.Holo.ActionButton` becomes `Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton`
- `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` becomes `Theme.Sherlock.LightDarkActionBar`
- `TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title` becomes `TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title`